# GUI programming with objective-c on Windows?

Tags: objective-c, windows, user-interface

Is it possible to do GUI programming using objective-c on Windows?

I am noticing that GNUstep contains headers for `AppKit` which is found here `/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/AppKit`

Should I install `Project Center` for that?Is it works? If there a way to write the GUI code by hand?

`EDIT:`

I just want to build simple utility GUI apps.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(void)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSView* myView = [[[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 100)]autorelease];

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

And I got:

```
$ gcc `gnustep-config --objc-flags` *.m  -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base
HelloGUI.m: In function 'main':
HelloGUI.m:7:10: warning: unused variable 'myView'
C:\Users\mhewedy\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvUXAIj.o:HelloGUI.m:(.data+0xa58): undefined reference to `__objc_class_name_NSView'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`The reasons I want to develop this app on windows is:`

1. The Target platform for this app to run on is Windows.
2. I don't have mac. (please don't ask me to buy one)

Thanks.

Comment: Yes but it is not recommended. Too many things can go wrong (And too many things go wrong in macosx already while programming an application ie. codesigning the application)

Comment: see my edit for the reason of the app

Comment: Even with that reason of yours, since the app is targeted to run on Mac, why not build it on Mac? Any reason why you are not doing it on Mac?

Comment: @محمد I don't understand the reason. You want to make a GUI right?

Comment: @Lukman: He didn't say he's targeting a Mac, he only said he wants to do GUI programming with Objective-C on Windows. You can do this on Linux with GNUstep just fine, so I assume it should work on Windows as well.

Comment: Fine. Windows it is. But why Objective-C? Objective-C is dominantly the language to develop an OSX app so, again, why Objective-C on Windows? There are C++, Delphi, VB, .NET, Java, Python etc, so why Objective-C? If for training/learning, then it's worth buying a Mac because when it's time to develop real app you'd have to get hold of one anyway.

Comment: mm, actually It is a way to div more into objective-C - which I know its basics - and In the same time I need to write some utility app for myself. besides I want to spent my weekend in some useful thing instead of wasting it :)

Comment: Okay, if you think having to tweak around (and pull out some hair while at it) is useful and not a waste of time, then be it. I pray somebody would help you in this. I wish you luck :)

Comment: Then you will waste your week-ends anyway ^^ You will waste a lot of time trying to solve a lot of issues you will have due to using ObjC on Windows (linking problems, dependencies issues, specific things that would work with ObjC & Cocoa on Mac but won't with GNUStep on Windows because OpenStep, even close to Cocoa, isn't Cocoa, ...) I think it's not worth it, you will probably loose less time learning a language/framework dedicated to Windows -- or use your ObjC skills on a Mac directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.
Check the following links

http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/index.html

http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WindowsAndButtons/index.html

To write code you can use notepad or 'Gemas' - a lightweight editor, which can be downloaded from the following link.

http://ftp.gnustep.org/pub/gnustep/binaries/windows/

Comment: I now able to run GUI (which is very bad) on Linux but not on win

Comment: @Muhammad : Any specific errors. Can you elaborate it?

I installed these  GNUStep [packages](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/Windows.html). on Windows 7 and run the GUI program which I mentioned in the above link with out any problems.

Answer (score 1):

include this library for linking

```
-lgnustep-gui
```