# Can i run objective c application on windows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mobile

I would like to learn something about i phone development. So, first i want to know that, Can i run basic application on windows? 
Is there any apps or tool available for the same. I knew, We can run this on Mac/Ubuntu. But, I have installed windows 7 in my laptop.

would be grateful for help.

Comment: i seem this link will solve problem.



   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113547/iphone-development-on-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [GUI programming with objective-c on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359703/gui-programming-with-objective-c-on-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For learning purpose you can install a virtual machine install OSX and try some of the examples (which i'm guessing is not legal). But if you want to create an app to upload it to the store you  **will** need a mac machine.

Comment: you said something is not legal??

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, and I have not read a MacOS license agreement in awhile. Apple used to have a clause in their MacOS EULA that forbade running MacOS in a VM unless the host machine was a Mac. I'm not sure if that's still true or not, but that's probably what @iNoob is referring to.

Comment: @strings42 yes that is what i was referring to, thanks for replying.